# .htaccess to nginx conf

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I have this .htaccess rewrite rules

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(administrator) - [L]
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

and the nginx version rewrite rules

```
charset utf-8;
rewrite ^/$ /public/ last;
rewrite /(.*) /public/$1 last;

location ~* ^/(administrator) {
    break;
}
```

The current .htaccess redirect all requests to /public folder except /administrator request. 
With the nginx rules the [domain.tld/rss.php **not working**] [domain.tld/administrator working] [domain.tld working] [File not found.]

My application stracture is

```
.
..
index.php [require public/index.php] 
administrator/index.php
public/index.php
public/rss.php
public/css
public/js
```

Answer (score 2):

Sepcifiy an index file : `index index.php`.

By the way you should put rewrite in locations to avoid the test for every request. It's also better for readability/maitainability.

```
server {

    server_name domain.tld;
    root /path/to/root;

    location ~ /(administrator|public) {
        index index.php;
        ...
    } 

    location / {
        rewrite ^/$ /public/ last;
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /public/$1 last;
    }

}
```